# How to install the taglist plugin in Vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I downloaded the taglist [plugin](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) and extracted it in my .vim folder.

I also installed **exuberant-ctags** from Synaptic.

I did `:TlistToggle` but it gives me the following message:

```
/bin/bash: D:ctags58ctags.exe: command not found
```

Am I missing something? Any suggestions?

Comment: I ask because this can impact the answer, was `.cim` supposed to be `.vim` and *exuberant-tags* *exuberant-ctags*?

Comment: It seems that the plugin is trying to use the windows version of exuberant-ctags for some reason. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about TagList or exuberant-ctags to be able to venture a guess as to why.

Comment: @chaz8705 Sorry, I made some little typos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the ctags command available in your path?

ctags --help should produce the help text.

If it is not you will need to add it to your path. Why it is trying to use a windows exe is beyond me.

Possibly something weird in a vimrc you got from a windows user or something?

Comment: i had something like: let...path...ctags.exe something in my .vimrc.

Answer (score 1):

For Vim 8 and beyond (>2018), installing through **plug** repository manager:

```
$ curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

once installed, make sure you have a **~/.vimrc** in your home folder.
open it (with vim) and add the lines:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'vim-scripts/taglist.vim'
call plug#end()
```

save your file (':wq!') 
open vim

```
:PlugInstall
```

and you should have it working!

the same works for any plugin hosted in github; just add between the call plug#begin() all the plugins you want to install (by referencing 'gitaccount/pluginname' (e.g. 'presevim/NERDTree') and you will add them to the install list.

Comment: IMHO, **vim-plug** is the best plugin manager for 'vim'.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install vim-scripts
```

check it:

```
dpkg -L vim-scripts |grep tag
/usr/share/doc/vim-scripts/html/macros_closetag.vim.html
/usr/share/doc/vim-scripts/html/plugin_taglist.vim.html
/usr/share/vim-scripts/plugin/wintagexplorer.vim
/usr/share/vim-scripts/plugin/taglist.vim
/usr/share/vim-scripts/doc/taglist.txt
/usr/share/vim-scripts/macros/closetag.vim
```